# The Antiderivative is uniformly continuous if the function is continuously differentiable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, uniform-continuity, lipschitz-functions

Let $g$ be a continuously differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$. Then, is the function $\int_0^xg\  dt$ uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$? Is it also lipschitz continuous? I think it is uniformly continuous, by using the fundamental theorem of calculus(or mean value theorem), but am unsure about the rigour of proof required. Any hints. Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Neither. $F(x)=x^2$ - or any polynomial of degree $\ge2$, for that matter - is not UC on $\Bbb R$, so $g(x)=2x$ is a counterexample.

Comment: thanks, was so silly of me!